# Does Trigger.io have support for Game Center on iOS?

Tags: ios, trigger.io

I am developing a simple game using Trigger.io. Does anyone know if Trigger.io supports integration with iOS Game Center?

Answer (score 0):

Probably this may answer your question http://docs.trigger.io/en/latest/release-notes.html#v1-4-14

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, currently there is no way to connect to iOS Game Center with Trigger.io.